# mysql Match against difficult to search chinese

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM store WHERE MATCH (name, type, location) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)
$query->bindValue(':search', '+'.$search.'*', PDO::PARAM_STR);
ft_min_word_len=2
```

I have a query MATCH AGAINST, it works fine in English

However in my database, I have a lots data are in Chinese, I have trouble to search those data

I did some testing & many words are difficult to find.

I have change ft_min_word_len to 2 words, since Chinese contain many 2 words phrase.

Do i need to adjust anything inside of my `my.ini` & how about character set? UTF8 GBk?

Also how to set up index for Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the collation, characters, connection are the same.

For example. If the word is stored as `utf8_general_ci`, ensure the connection is in utf8 and the word-to-be-searched is utf8 too.

Comment: words is stored as utf8_general_ci, so how to ensure the connection is utf8?

Comment: PDO: `"mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8"` or $dbh->exec("set names utf8"); mysqli: http://www.php.net/mysqli_set_charset

Comment: :( still have trouble to find the content

Comment: If the collation, character and connection are right. Does the Chinese characters display correctly in phpMyAdmin? If it doesn't, it probably didn't get save correctly, so that explains why you can't search.

Comment: i use copy & paste from phpMyadmin, does it affect? I have try LIKE %:search%, and I have no problem to search those data

Comment: If you have no problem searching in phpMyAdmin, then check whether the input is in utf8, or convert it into utf8.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45805/discussion-between-ben-wong-and-hongtat)